# Pass WPF Datagrid.SelectedItems to BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync()

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, backgroundworker, wpfdatagrid

I've bound a wpf DataGrid to an ObservableCollection of a class called pictures and I wont to work with the selected items in a BackgroundWorker.

Obviously, I could copy all the data to new ObservableCollection item by item.

Since I'm very new to C#, I wonder whether there is an easy/elegant/better way to pass the SelectedItems collection to the BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync() method and work with them as picture objects?

Thanks!

Edit:

With the application I want to select files (mostly pictures) from a datagrid and upload these files to a sharepoint site. I works fine without the BackgroundWorder. However, the files can be big and the number of upload is up to a 100 files / pictures. Hence, I want to use a BackgroundWorker to update the UI every now and then.

Edit II:
The Datagrid is bound like this

```
Datagrid.Itemssource = vm.getfiles(folderpath); //where getfiles is ObservableCollection<picture>
```

When I call the RunWorkerAsync like this:

bgw.RunWorkerAsync(Datagrid.SelectedItems)

and try to access them in the DoWork like this

```
ObservableCollection<picture> si = (ObservableCollection<picture>)e.Argument;
```

I get an System.InvalidCastException: The Object of Type System.Windows.Controls.SelectedItemCollection can not changed to MyApp.ObservableCollection.

Answer (score 0):

If you using the MVVM pattern I would take the model, if it doesn't implement  INotifyPropertyChanged. Then with your model you can make sure that you safely make changes to the object. Once your BackgroundWorker complete's its task you can then raise the proper PropertyChanged events on each ViewModel that should wrap your model.This way the changes are then reflected in the view. The models would be passed in as an expected argument in its own list. The observable collection should not be referenced in the BackgroundThread (Unless you really need it to update the UI and even then you will need to send an action to the dispatcher).

A significant amount of this advice can be taken with a large grain of salt. However, this is the general way I would approach a problem with needing to do a large amount of work in a background thread with out worrying about the UI Thread update problems.

Comment: Well, I am also new to the MVVM approach and tried to implent it. So the picture class implements the  INotifyPropertyChanged. Are the selected items in the datagrid marked in some way in the ObservableCollection that is bound as itemssource so I could access only these items from the ObservableCollection ?

Comment: The ObservableCollection is basically a container that will update anything that is bound to the collection. The items in the collection are bound to the the ItemTemplates used in the control. If you update your items, the picture class, and it raises the PropertyChanged event in the background thread you will get an exception about needing to update the UI in the UI thread. So what you should do is separate out the  core data from the Business Logic. This is basically creating a viewmodel and model. Yes you can interact with the objects but they are likely to go wrong, due to UI update evetns

Comment: The picture class has some properties like sharepoinSite and sharepointLibrary. If these are updated, the ui is updated (so this works kind of nice). The picture class also has a method called UploadToSharepoint (this is the one I want to call in the BackgroundWorker).
The main thing I am wondering about, is what the best way is, to tell the BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync method, which items in the Datagrid have been selected.

Comment: If your only concern is how to pass it the selected list, is to create a temporary list of items and pass it in as an argument. Once it exits the scope the references will be collected in the garbage. Since it should just be references to the list items in the observable collection it should be small, and there will be no conflicts.